# When I try to display text to the screen every 10 seconds, it never works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to enable a text that says "LEVEL UP" with TextMeshPro every 10 seconds the game is running but I've kept searching and can't find anything that has helped fix this problem. I've also seen code that has the InvokeRepeating method but from what I've tried that doesn't work either.

Heres the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class LevelUp : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI LevelUpText;
    public int NumberOfSeconds;
    void Update() {  

        if(Time.time % 10 == 0 && Time.time != 0) {
            StartCoroutine(EnableText());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator EnableText() {
        LevelUpText.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(NumberOfSeconds);
        LevelUpText.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use a Coroutine for both delays, the time with and without the text instead of `Update`?

Answer (score 0):

Time.time most probably will never be fully divisible by 10. Since Update is called every frame, you might get an update at time t=9.6 and then the next frame at t=10.1
Using a coroutine, you could create an infinite loop, like so.

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(TextRoutine());
}

public IEnumerator TextRoutine() {
    while(true) {
        LevelUpText.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(BlinkDelaySeconds);
        LevelUpText.enabled = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(LevelUpDelaySeconds);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use InvokeRepeating, you would have to create a function that starts your coroutine (rather than calling the coroutine directly as a function)

```
void Start() {
    InvokeRepeating("EnableText", NumberOfSeconds, 0f);
}

void EnableText() {
    StartCoroutine(EnableTextRoutine());
}

IEnumerator EnableTextRoutine() ...
```